# fatfs : By using f_mkdir() function creating Unknown type file inside the folder

Tags: c, fatfs

I want to know that after using `f_mkdir()` function I am creating "SENT" folder but in that folder, one more "SENT" file/folder is created which does not have any description.

```
iFResult = f_stat("/SENT" ,&File_Info);     // Check "SENT" folder is 
// present or not, if not present then create it.    
if(iFResult > FR_OK)
{
    iFResult = f_mkdir("/SENT");    //  Create a new directory 
}
```

I cannot understand the problem is with my code. Any help is appreciated.

[image: snapshot of "SENT" properties]

[fatfs: Generic FAT Filesystem Module]

Comment: What is the value of `iFResult` after both `f_stat` and `f_mkdir`?

Comment: After successful completion of this function, it will return zero and not successful it will return non zero value.                                                              for more reference:- http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/rc.html

Comment: I know that. My question was what values do they actually return when you run as above, particularly after `f_mkdir`? Also, do other operating systems report `SENT` as being a file, or only Windows?

Comment: When SD card is empty, then on the first iteration "f_stat" return "FR_NO_FILE" i.e 4 as it is enum  type  and "f_mkdir" return the " FR_OK" (0) and on the 2 iterations it "f_stat" return  " FR_OK"  and it did not when inside the "if " conditions.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried reading the SD card with another operating system? How did you format the SD card, with Windows or with fsfat? Also, does fsfat itself think that `SKIP` is a directory or a file?

Comment: `SENT`, not `SKIP`...

Comment: I am formatting with fat32 in windows only and I took the sd card in the ubuntu there I got to know it is file only which have missing data from another file.While debugging I get to know that in renaming the file buffer is missing the data and file got renamed with "SENT" and missing the extension.

Answer (score 1):

`if(iFResult > FR_OK)` seems wrong. According to the documentation you must test:

```
if (iFresult == FR_NO_FILE) {
    // file or subdir does not exist
}
else if (iFresult != FR_OK) {
    // error
}
else // file/subdir exists
```

Comment: I am not working on windows. I am working on TM4C1294NCPDT microcontroller with this third-party filesystem. I am using reference and sample codes as per the vendor from this given link down.                              http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html